# Is there any way to block only allowed IP Address can Access BitBucket or GitHub Repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-fork

I am working on a web application project and keep all the files in bitbucket repository with my colleagues in office.

Is there any way to limit he access of repository only on my office. ?

Comment: Well you can buy a private repo .but bitbucket provides it for free upto a few users

Comment: dude. private repository not having ip blocking in their plans i think. I want to access the repo form only in my office.

Comment: I dont think so bitbucket provide this, but if it is really important for you host bitbucket on your own server https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/download and there you can do anything you want to do.

Comment: what is the use of SSH keys in git.